# Linq Attach Child entity to PArent based on common field

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a parent and child as separate objects. Now I have to combine both based on the join condition.
My entities are

```
public class Customer
    {
        private int customerId;
        private string customerName;
        private List<Order> orders;
    }

public class Order
{
    private int customerId;
    private int orderId;
    private string OrderName;
}
```

Here, customerId is the join field.

I have list of customers, but it has only CustomerId and CustomerName data. It doesn't have Orders ( order object is empty for each customer)
I have _orders as separate object like below.

```
List<Customer> _customers;
List<Order> _orders;
```

Now I have to join both and finally, I need _customers object which should have _orders as well.

I have used foreach statement to attach the orders to each customer like below.

```
 _customers.ForEach(c =>
                {
                    c.orders = _orders.Where(o => o.customerId == c.customerId).ToList();
                });
```

But, I want to exclude foreach loop and trying to get through join condition.
Could someone help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`GroupJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1) to achieve this :

```
List<Customer> result = _customers.GroupJoin(_orders,
    c => c.customerId,
    o => o.customerId,
    (c, o) => new Customer
    {
        customerId = c.customerId,
        customerName = c.customerName,
        orders = o.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Test in dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/OJN480

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks Sajid.. this is perfect